# How does the data attribute in the attribute src of script tag work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, ecmascript-6

I hava some js code below,what's the data in src? how does it works?

`script.src = "data:text/javascript,inc++"`

details:

```
    <script>
        //Initialize the "inc" to zero.
        var inc = 0;
        //Get the HEAD element from the document.
        var head = document.documentElement.firstChild;
        //Create and initialize SCRIPT elements in a loop,
        //they will execute 2 times of the "inc++" code.
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.src = "data:text/javascript,inc++"; // how does the data works?
            head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
            script.onload = function () {
                console.log(inc);
            };
        };
    </script>
```

the src value should be setted a url,but this does not. why so?

Comment: It is a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)

Comment: use `script.src = "data:text/javascript," + inc++; `

Comment: I believe you would need to encode it with base 64

Comment: @לבני-מלכה that would be `"data:text/javascript,0"`

Comment: @jro I know it looks like the OP wats it (see he initializes the "inc" to zero.)

Comment: @לבני-מלכה but he wants to add a script that that increments inc, not increment it in the main code

Answer (score 1):

From the [MDN docs for the script tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script):

> src
>
> This attribute specifies the URI of an external script; **this can be used as an alternative to embedding a script directly within a document.**
>
> ⚠️ If a script element has a src attribute specified, it should not have a script embedded inside its tags.

How can you embed a script directly within a document (other than embedding it between `<script>` tags)?

Here's another excerpt from [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs), on data URI:

> Data URLs, URLs prefixed with the data: scheme, allow content creators to embed small files inline in documents.

`data:text/javascript` indicates that it's a javascript document. Other type of interest is `data:text/html`, you can also do something like `data:text/html,<script>/* some js code */</script>`

I have seen it being more commonly used to embed small image in css, i.e

```
div {
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,....); <-- image encoded in base64
}
```

So your example is basically equivalent to:

```
<script>
  var inc = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    inc++;
    console.log(inc);
  };
</script>
```

Your excerpt of code perhaps is meant to explain how script tags behave.